# Give access to a set of DAGS to a "builtin readonly role"

Tags: airflow, rbac, flask-appbuilder

I am trying to follow https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#role-based to give a user role access to certain DAGs.

While the example `FAB_ROLES`

```py
FAB_ROLES = {
    "ReadOnly": [
        [".*", "can_list"],
        [".*", "can_show"],
        [".*", "menu_access"],
        [".*", "can_get"],
        [".*", "can_info"]
    ]
}
```

should give read access to anything, when accessing the /home view with such role the DAG list is empty.

I tried extending those permissions with

```py
from airflow.security import permissions

# ...

    + [
        [permissions.resource_name_for_dag(dag), action]
        for dag in ["my-dag"]
        for action in permissions.DAG_ACTIONS
    ]
```

but that was not helpful.